# Android create a "flat button"

Tags: android, android-layout, button

Supposedly, in the material theme, there are two types of buttons: raised, and flat:

[image: Raised and Flat]

When I create a `<Button>`, it looks like the "raised" button. How, using markup, can I make the "flat button". Is there any style or attribute to do it? I found this image in the theme editor.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use the `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle` on your `Button` as follows:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextGoesHere"
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
/>
```

[`BorderlessButtonStyle`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/R.attr.html#borderlessButtonStyle)

> Style for buttons without an explicit border, often used in groups.

Also you can use those [`Flat Buttons`](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#flat-button)

Comment: Thanks. I wish Google would make this stuff easier to find. There is still too many Holo themes left over.

Comment: Oh and do these still respond with a material "ripple" when pressed?

Comment: Like this: http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html#responsive-interaction-user-input

Comment: Can we apply borderlessButtonStyle progrmatically?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS i posted it here please - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50295530/1828637

Comment: I also posted this question please sir - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50295600/1828637

Answer (score 9):

Add dependency to `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

Then in your layout XML file, add a style attribute to the Button

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
```

You can change the color when the button is pressed by defining a custom style

```
<style name="FlatButtonStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and applying this style in layout XML

```
android:theme="@style/FlatButtonStyle"
```

Answer (score 4):

With the availability of **[Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)**, it is now easy to add a *Flat Button* in your layout.
Here are the steps:

Add dependency to your app module's `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'
}
```

> Note: Find the latest version number at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material

Then add a MaterialButton with the following style to your XML layout

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

And that's it. The style property and its value `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"` takes care of enabled and disabled states and its text color.

Final result:

[image]